# checkjni error happen when use android studio build apk, while use unity build apk run well

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

with my jni demo, i use CallStaticIntMethod to call java method with boolean return. then i build this to .so, when i use this so in android studio project, the app will crash with error message like:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallStaticIntMethodV does not match boolean a.sheng.navivelibrary.NativeUtils.callBoolean().
what confuse me is that this work well when i use the so in unity project and build android apk with unity.
i have checked the gradle\ndk settings in unity or android studio, but cannot find the reason why this differences happen.
anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem:
1, choose Development Build will open checkjni in unity, then will get this error
2, build debug will open checkjni while build release will close checkjni with android studio